# Generar QR en php

Tags: php, html, qrcode, qr

Estoy tratando de generar un QR en php a partir de ciertos datos que extraigo del sistema.
Lo primero que hago es crear el directorio donde se va a almacenar la imagen del QR, luego defino la "calidad del QR", luego el mama~o y por ultimo comienzo genero el QR a partir de los pasos anteriores y de los datos que extraigo.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id_user']) && isset($_REQUEST['nombre_responsable'])) { 

    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test'.md5($_REQUEST['id_user'].'|'.$_REQUEST['nombre_responsable'].'|'.$errorCorrectionLevel.'|'.$matrixPointSize).'.png';
    QRcode::png($_REQUEST['id_user'], $_REQUEST['nombre_responsable'], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);    

  }    

//imprimo la imagen del QR
echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" />';
```

El problema es que al usar el dato 'nombre_responsable' deja de generarme el QR, únicamente he logrado hacer que se genere a partir del ID que le envio.

Dejo imagenes del sistema para que se hagan una idea.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Coloca código en lugar de imagen, hay usuarios con problemas en la vista y según lo que tengo entendido, no distinguen lo que hay.

Comment: No estás pasando los parámetros a `QRcode::png` en el orden correcto. Revisa la documentación : http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/docs/html/class_q_rcode.html